# Looking for spatially referenced aerial photos

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa, aerial-photography

I am trying to find a source of spatially referenced aerial photos that can be analyzed with ArcGIS or R. I cannot use Google Earth because I have nothing to georeference it to. I know they are out there but it has been years since I have used to program. Specifically, I am looking for Napa County, California.

Comment: can you elaborate on why you have nothing to georeference to in google earth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[USGS' Earth Explorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) is an excellent resource for this type of imagery (unless the US Govt is on shutdown).

In this case I would look for NAIP imagery in your area of interest.